# c# Reset ListView after buttom submit is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a page for user to select word documents and do documents merge. There is a ListView containing a label, a dropdownlist and a delete button. The ListView contain one row when the page load, users can add / delete rows during run-time. When submit button click, it will do documents merge and stream to download the output file. My problem is, file is downloaded after clicking the submit button  but the dropdownlist in ListView are not removed. How to reset the ListView to the original state after clicking submit button?

In Default.aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvDynamicControls" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderId="itemPlaceholder" 
    OnItemDataBound="lvDynamicControls_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="lyDynamicControls_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblService" runat="server" Text="Service"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddControls" runat="server" Text="Add more" OnClick="btnAddControls_click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
    onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" 
    onclick="btnClear_Click" />
```

Part of the code in Default.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindListView();  
        }
    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> selectedFiles = this.GetSelectedFiles();
        this.MergeDocuments(selectedFiles);
        this.ClearListView();
    }
    private void MergeDocuments(List<string> filenames)
    {
         // code for merging documents here...
         // stream file to download
         Response.Clear();
         Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=output.docx");
         mem.Position = 0;
         mem.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
         Response.End();
    }
    protected void ClearListView()
    {
        // create a new dataTable with 1 row and update datasource
        this.SetDataSource(this.CreateDataTable());
        this.lvDynamicControls.Items.Clear();
        this.lvDynamicControls.DataSource = null;
        this.lvDynamicControls.DataBind();
        this.BindListView();
    }
    protected void BindListView()
    {
        DataTable dataSource = this.GetDataSource();
        this.lvDynamicControls.DataSource = dataSource;
        this.lvDynamicControls.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: `this.ClearListView();` is never called. There is a `Response.End();` in `MergeDocuments` that is called before ClearListView is. And even if it were it won't work because a file is sent to the browser, not the updated webpage where the list has been cleared.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. this.ClearListView() is called actually, but your are right. There is a Response.End(); that is called before ClearListView and the webpage will never update.